# i am unable to import file or folder in react

Tags: reactjs, import

I'm unable to import the file or folder in app.js in react app, it gives me errors like this Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /orders2 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/ or add a symlink to it from the project's

I try to display my other component in the react app and display it as output but when I do this it is giving me an error like this still, I am in my src directory but it gives an error like Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /orders2 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/ or add a symlink to it from the project's

Comment: did you move it inside `/src` folder as recommended in the error message?

Comment: If you read the message you will find your answer: "You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's"=> (1) Move the file inside scr/  OR (2) Add a symlink to it from project, but this is generally not recommended unless you have a very good reason to do so. if you need to use symlink then: [Symlinks in Linux/Unix](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/), [Symlinks in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink),[Webpack and Symlinks]

Answer (score -1):

The error message you've encountered points to an issue where you're attempting to import a file or folder located outside the "src" directory within your React project. React enforces a strict policy for import paths, which generally requires imports to be relative to the "src" directory or from installed packages via npm or yarn.

To address this problem, you have several options:

**Option 1)** Move the File/Folder Inside the "src" Directory: The simplest and recommended solution is to relocate the "orders2" file or folder inside the "src" directory of your project. This aligns with best practices and ensures smoother imports.
Project Structure:

```
- project-directory
  - src
    - app.js
    - orders2.js
```

You can then import it in "app.js" like this:

```
import Orders2 from './orders2';
```

**Option 2)** Use Symlinks: If moving the file/folder inside "src" isn't feasible or desirable, you can create a symbolic link (symlink) from the "src" directory to the external location. This allows you to import it as if it were within "src."
To create a symlink from the project's root directory (assuming you're on a Unix-like system), use a command like this:

```
ln -s /path/to/orders2 ./src/orders2
```

Then, you can import it in "app.js" as if it were part of "src":

```
import Orders2 from './orders2';
```

**Option 3)** Custom Webpack Configuration: If you have a specific, compelling reason to keep the file/folder outside "src," you can customize your webpack configuration to allow imports from external locations. However, this approach isn't recommended unless you have a valid use case, as it deviates from React's standard project structure.

To customize your webpack configuration, you can use the "eject" command to access the configuration files. Keep in mind that this is an advanced step that should be approached cautiously.

In most cases, option 1 (moving the file/folder inside "src") is the simplest and best practice. It aligns with React's conventions and ensures smooth imports, making your project more maintainable and easier to understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).